# Android - Repeatedly Created Bitmaps causes failure

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, decode, encode

A1: 
Within the app i load *4* base64 strings of my server and creates thumbnails in the app.
Creates views for them and adding them to a scroll layout.
No problems this far.

A1-A1-A1++
If i repeat A1 again and again - adding 5 image and  5 more images to the layout ... - no problems.

A2:
Still within the app - going reverse to the main activity.
Heading into a new activity - picture choosing activity.
Loads an image from the gallery choosing part of the app.
Creates an image prewiew.
No problems this far.

A2-A2-A2++
If i repeat A2 again and again after this - no problems.

A1-A2-A2-A2++
If i do A1 and repeat A2 again and again - no problems.

A1-A2-A1-A2
If i start with A1 and do A2 and return to A1 and then A2, it crashes when it should be creating the preview image.

A1:

```
     int count = 1;
        while (count < 5)
           {


                try {


                    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
                    String imei = mngr.getDeviceId();
                    String image_count = String.valueOf(count);
                    String user_image = new GetUserImagesActivity().execute(imei,image_count).get();                                                                
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(user_image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    /*BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(decodedByte);*/        



                //ImageView Setup
                ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
                imageView1.setTag(count);
                imageView1.setOnTouchListener(this);
                //setting image resource
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                //setting image position        

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                params2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;            
                imageView1.setLayoutParams(params2);                       


                imageView1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView1.setMaxHeight(240);
                imageView1.setMaxWidth(180);
                /*imageView.setMinimumHeight(180);
                imageView.setMinimumWidth(240);*/
                imageView1.setId(110011);
                imageView1.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
                //adding view to layout
                top_container.addView(imageView1);

                count++;

   //Tried this to solve the problem//
                imageView1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imageView1.buildDrawingCache();

                //Causes images to get black//
                /*decodedByte.recycle();*/

               } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "problem 1" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();  
            } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "problem 2" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }

           }
```

A2: - New Images to server (fails at preview)

```
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.DATA);
                String fileSrc = cursor.getString(idx);

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc);
                // load  // preview  // image
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 480, 640, false);
                // bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapPreview);
                img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Log:

```
        11-08 16:44:58.293: D/dalvikvm(22771): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 44K, 34% free 22390K/33571K, paused 23ms

        11-08 16:44:58.293: E/dalvikvm-heap(22771): Out of memory on a 36000016-byte allocation.  

        11-08 16:44:58.303: W/dalvikvm(22771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9f210)

        11-08 16:44:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(22771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

        11-08 16:44:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(22771): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

        11-08 16:44:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(22771):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)

        11-08 16:44:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(22771):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)

        11-08 16:44:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(22771):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:305)
```

Comment: what is the stacktrace when you crash?

Comment: Running the code on my testphone, as eclipse is teasing me. Could i include a stacktrace and "toast" it ?

Comment: When you run it with USB debugging enabled, it would print the crash stacktrace to logcat in red.

Comment: Ok, please enlighten me.. Because i don't see/know where i should get this ?

Comment: Ok.. i really see that that i have missed a great deal of info there. It is causing outofmemomy.

Comment: On your android, enable USB debugging -> connect your android to your laptop -> In eclpise, click menu "Window":"Show View":"Other" -> find LogCat under Android then click it -> run your app

Comment: Just added the part of log where it crashes.

Comment: There is nothing after fatal:exception main? that is the important part. It should say: `SomethingException at ...`

Comment: added more from the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was:

```
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();        

                options.inDither = false;
                options.inSampleSize = 6;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc,options);                                                                                                    

                img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

As well i added bao.close(); and bitmap.recycle(); this when making the base64 image string and closed the activity: Code looking like this:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        String text = Base64.encodeToString(ba,0);
        try {
            bao.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bitmap.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bitmap class, Use WeakReference classes;

Like 
instead of this line.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc);
```

use this.

```
WeakReference<Bitmap> bitmap=new WeakReference<Bitmap>(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc));
```

WeakReference is special type in android, which clean out from memory fast w.r.t other objects.

Comment: This causes errors on CreateScaledBitmap and setImageBitmap - Eclipse wants to change parts, to something that does not make sense.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory error means: you don't have enough memory to load more bitmaps.

Possible solutions:

only keep a cache of a max number of pictures.

and/or reduce the inSampleSize when you load the pictures through BitmapFactory

try reading: [Displaying Bitmaps Effeciently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: I expected this was the case - since everything could run by itself - own activity repeatedly without crash, and i did know this documentation, but i don't see something which makes sense directly in relation to what i am doing.

Comment: Let me re-phrase. I don't see an explanation to what helps where and why. As you see from my code, i all ready tried to recycle images and cache images, because i know i am flooding the memory. I am not re-using the images, so if i could flush all the images present in one activity @ activity change, this would be what i am looking for.

Comment: Have you lowered the inSampleSize when you decode the Bitmaps, and when activity changes, you can call `recycle()` on all your Bitmaps to free their memory ASAP

Comment: Calling recycle was not a solution for the dynamic loaded images, as they are not defined within an area that is "available".. i am not experienced enough on that part. On the new images selection activity i have added recycle() on activity change, close bytearrayoutputstream on activity change and inSampleSize on creation of the preview image. It seems this did the trick.

Comment: I added the 3 things to the code and I can't make it crash now!